# Can fonts be displayed as contextual character combinations?

Tags: fonts, font-design, grep, publishing, epub

Looking for way to do a handwriting font but where certain letter sequences or patterns display together. Would the method be to put the two or three or four letters together as one, as uncommonly used UTF symbol or alt language character, then use that character in place of common ASCI text. Focus is HTML/CSS.

Or just use a set of fonts and style a span element class for handwriting font variance based on letter combos?

Or, is there built in 'smart' interpretation in browser engines for/or w3c stylesheet specs that can acheive this. Or other software aside HTML/CSS that can achieve this for visual presentation or publishing.

Added the grep tag to the post wondering if a sed/regex or node/regex file for letter combos to parse/find and replace font family or font character pre publishing (bash sed) or post (node js)  is the only way to acheive this.

Examples:

ex would flow together,
fx would not

ti would flow together,
ji would not

let get and set flow together,
bet does not

Comment: The font file can do this, so yes.

Comment: Could you explain or demonstrate?